# Retroactively use Mercurial rename

Tags: mercurial

In my project, I haven't been using `hg remove`, `hg mv` or `hg addremove` due to ignorance. Consequently, every time I've renamed or moved a file, the history of that file has been messed up and now when I look at an individual file's history, I will only see a portion of the history.

What I'm looking for is a way to go back and retroactively fix all of those renaming mistakes so that the file history will stay together. What I imagine would be most likely is a way to edit the data in ".hg\store\data" to make this work. I've been experimenting, and I see the lines `copy:` and `copyrev:` in the data for the files I've renamed, so I suspect that has something to do with it.

Assume that I have control of the central repository and that there are no clones of it currently.

Comment: I have no experience in actually doing this, and expect it might be anywhere from a little bit to very painful especially if there are any merges, but `hg histedit` should be able to achieve this. Your task essentially boils down to making a new history, starting from the point at which the first file renames or copies should have been noted, and going forward for every commit after that point. The mechanics of this are straightforward enough, but whether `histedit` will allow it, even if you force all the commits to draft phrase, I do not know.

Comment: If `histedit` does not allow merges (the documentation suggests that this is the case) and there are merges, the alternative is to build the new commits manually in a clone of the original repository from which all the "to be changed" history has been `hg strip`ped. Then, for each subsequent non-merge commit, extract it from the original repository, place it in the working directory, and do any `hg add` or `hg mv` etc required and commit. For each subsequent merge commit, re-perform the merge, obtaining resolutions from the other repository if necessary.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to fix this without recreating the repo. You might be able to use the convert extension? In the future you might consider turning on the automv extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AutomvExtension

Comment: @nathan12343 I was searching for something like that - thanks!

Comment: @torek thanks for the idea - I ended up doing basically the same thing with MQ, unfortunately it only got me until the most recent merge in the repository, but it was sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary:

Since you have full control of the repo this can be 100% fixed using normal hg commands.

The principle idea is to insert new changesets in the right places which effectively correct the original ones.

---

Let's say your history looks like this:

```
A-B-C-*
```

(`*` is your working folder)

and it was in `B` that you renamed a file in the filesystem without renaming it in hg.

Do this:

```
hg up A
hg revert -r B --all
hg mv oldfilename newfilename
hg commit -m <message>
```

The key here is using `revert` which is used to copy changes from a changeset into your working folder. This *only works this way* because you have updated to the predecessor of the changeset you are reverting.

at this point your history looks like:

```
A-B-C
 \
  B'-*
```

where `B'` is the "corrected" variant of `B`. Continue with:

```
hg rebase -s C -d B'
```

and you have:

```
A-B
 \
  B'-C-*
```

You can now clean up by doing:

```
hg strip B
```

leaving just:

```
A-B'-C-*
```

---

Of course where I used revisions like `B` you need to type the actual revision # or hash.

You could also use TortoiseHG or some other GUI to do a lot of these steps.

Answer (score 1):

This answer covers the situation where you do NOT have full control of the repo. Its a little trickier and you can't get quite as clean of a result, but it still can be dealt with using normal hg commands.

The principle idea is to insert new changesets in the right places which effectively correct the original ones, and merge them after the fact.

---

Let's say your history looks like this:

```
A-B-C-*
```

(`*` is your working folder)

and it was in `B` that you renamed a file in the filesystem without renaming it in hg.

Do this:

```
hg up A
hg mv oldfilename newfilename
hg commit -m <message>
```

at this point your history looks like:

```
A-B-C
 \
  B'-*
```

where `B'` is the "corrected" variant of `B`. Continue with:

```
hg up C
hg merge B'
hg commit
```

and you have:

```
A-B-C-D-*
 \   /
  B'
```

If you look at the file history of the file in question, it will look something like this:

```
o   D   merge
|\
| o B'  rename file
| |
o | B   change where the file should have been renamed
  |
  o A   some earlier change
 /
o   ...
|
o   ...
```

So the history is all linked together for the file. Its just a little weird that B looks like it started from nowhere (because it actually did).